# How does SSMS grab the name of my server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019, instance

In the bottom-right hand side of SSMS's main screen and to the left of where it shows my user-name and the name of the database that I'm in, it gives the name of the server that I'm on. This string is the same as what I put in the "Server name" field when connecting to the server when I first open SSMS and is also shown in the Object Explorer. How does SSMS determine this name? I've tried

```sql
SELECT 
  HOST_NAME(),
  @@SERVICENAME,
  DB_NAME,
  @@SERVERNAME,
  SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName'),
  SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')
```

but only `SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')` returns a substring of what SSMS shows. The rest have nothing at all to do with the string in question.

Comment: "This string is the same as what I put in the "Server name" field" - so why does it need to "grab it" from anywhere? You have already told it

Comment: @MartinSmith There is always value in knowing how to programmatically retrieve a useful value.

Comment: @J.Mini Your reply to Martin Smith makes it sound like you misunderstood what he was saying. Is it clear that it's likely stored in the application's Memory because you told it what the server name is?

Comment: @J.D. If you can prove that is where SSMS pulls the string from, then that's an answer to the question.

Comment: The only way of "proving" it would be too decompile the SSMS assemblies and look. Personally I have zero motivation to do this. You have already told it the server name to connect to. Object Explorer and New Query windows themselves make a connection to the database using this information so I'm not getting why you think it is a mystery that they are able to display the same information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accepted Alocyte's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/335275/170408), but you want more evidence. Let's give it a try.

I have a SQL Server. The server's name is 100002-DB28. The instance name is Fam7_Test. We'll start with ...

### The control case

Connecting to it as `100002-DB28\Fam7_Test`:

[image: SSMS connect dialog]

We can see that `select @@servername` gives us the server/instance name, and the status bar of SSMS shows the same.

[image: SSMS query results]

### Variation #1

I have a DNS alias (a CNAME) for that server, calling it DataNREngineTest. So I can connect to it as `DataNREngineTest\Fam7_Test`:

[image: SSMS connect dialog]

This time, the SSMS status bar reflects the name I used in the Connect dialog, even though the result of `select @@servername` shows that it's still the same server as before.

[image: SSMS query results]

### Variation #2

Let's use the IP address. I can connect to it as `172.16.100.207\Fam7_Test`:

[image: SSMS connect dialog]

This time, the SSMS status bar reflects the IP address I used in the Connect dialog, and the result of `select @@servername` shows that it's *still* the same server as before.

[image: SSMS query results]

### Variation #3

Let's use the port number instead of the instance name. I can connect to it as `172.16.100.207,52043`:

[image: SSMS connect dialog]

This time, the SSMS status bar reflects the IP address *and* port number I used in the Connect dialog, and the result of `select @@servername` shows that it's *still* the same server as before.

[image: SSMS query results]

### Variation #4

It's not much different from the IP address case, but let's run SSMS locally on the server and use the local loopback address of 127.0.0.1. I can connect to it as `127.0.0.1\Fam7_Test`:

[image: SSMS connect dialog]

This time, the SSMS status bar reflects the loopback address *and* port number I used in the Connect dialog, and the result of `select @@servername` shows that it's *still* the same server as before.

[image: SSMS query results]

### Variation #5

This one is not much different than the DNS alias of Variation #1, but it is easier for others to reproduce if they don't have access to make DNS changes. Let's use a Hosts file entry pointing `demo4dba_se` to the SQL server. I can connect to it as `demo4dba_se\Fam7_Test`:

[image: SSMS connect dialog]

This time, the SSMS status bar again reflects the name (from the Hosts file) that I used in the Connect dialog, and the result of `select @@servername` shows that it's *still* the same server as before.

[image: SSMS query results]

That's six different cases where the SSMS status bar shows whatever I entered in the Connect to Server dialog.

### Summary

What Alocyte said, but with pretty pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Derived from you connection string.
Try target public IP, or URL, or internal IP, or netbios name... will mirror whatever you use.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this? Even a series of screenshots would do.

Comment: Hi - can't expose IP / URL - try changing your connection to the same server and observe: if you are locally connecting, try 127.0.0.1, then ., then machine name, then public URL (assuming its configured for internet access)...